# JSON-C installation in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, c, json, codeblocks

I was trying to install the JSON-C library to my Codeblocks, but I faced a problem.
I have downloaded the JSON-C library from here : https://github.com/json-c/json-c
I was following this tutorial : http://ccm.net/faq/29303-install-a-library-under-codeblocks-for-mingw
As the tutorial says, the second step is linking the ".a" file to the project. I couldn't find them, nor the .dll files mentioned in the next step.

How can I proceed?

Comment: There will be no `.a` or `.dll` files until you build the library. You
can't install it until you build it and you haven't done that. You have merely downloaded the source code. Read [the README file](https://github.com/json-c/json-c) and the
repository's [home page](https://github.com/json-c/json-c/wiki).

Comment: That's very interesting. And can you tell me how do I compile the library? Should I put all the .c and .h file in a project and compile it?

Comment: The README file that you have already read explains how to build the library: **Building on Unix with git, gcc and autotools**. That is how it must be done. On Windows, you will need a Unix-like environment to do this, e.g. [MYSYS2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/)
or [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). You may have noticed that the tarball contains a `json-c.vcproj` project file for Visual Studio, but a library built with VC++ will not link with MingGW binaries.

Comment: Thank, man. You are really use full :)